# Trouble with string in Delphi

Tags: string, delphi, delphi-7

I have a random string of numbers
(numbers can only be used once, only from 1-9, almost any length(min 1,max 9)):

```
var
Input: String;
begin
Input := '431829576'; //User inputs random numbers
```

**And now I need to get specified number to front**. How about `5`.

```
var
Number: Integer;
begin
Number := 5;
```

and function executes with result `543182976`.

I don't have any ideas how to make a function like this, Thanks.

Comment: So what do you do to solve your problem and how does it comes to wrong result?

Comment: @Krom, obviously - posting questions to stuckoverflaw :)

Comment: Why did my question is downvoted?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
function ForceDigitInFront(const S: string; const Digit: Char): string;
begin
  result := Digit + StringReplace(S, Digit, '', []);
end;
```

A more lightweight solution is

```
function ForceDigitInFront(const S: string; const Digit: Char): string;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  result := S;
  for i := 1 to Length(S) do
    if result[i] = Digit then
    begin
      Delete(result, i, 1);
      break;
    end;
  result := Digit + result;
end;
```

Comment: constant object can not be passed as var parameter `Delete(result, i, 1);
`

Comment: Hey @Andreas! Change `S` to `Digit` in your first function. And I will accept your answer.

Comment: What if `S` does not contain `Digit`? Is `51234` the desired output for the inputs `1234` and `5`?

Answer (score 4):

You could do it this way :

```
function ForceDigitInFront(const S: string; const Digit: Char): string;
var
  dPos : Integer;
begin
  Result := s;
  dPos := Pos( Digit,S);
  if (dPos <> 0) then begin  // Only apply Digit in front if Digit exists !?
    Delete( Result,dPos,1);
    Result := Digit + Result;
  end;
end;
```

If Digit is not in input string, the digit is not added here, but change this if it does not fit your implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that reduces the numer of String allocations needed, as well as checks if the digit is already in the front:

```
function ForceDigitInFront(const S: string; const Digit: Char): string; 
var 
  dPos : Integer; 
begin 
  Result := s; 
  for dPos := 1 to Length(Result) do
  begin
    if Result[dPos] = Digit then
    begin
      if dPos > 1 then
      begin
        UniqueString(Result);
        Move(Result[1], Result[2], (dPos-1) * SizeOf(Char));
        Result[1] := Digit;
      end;
      Exit;
    end;
  end;
end;
```